# what is the page for entering pyvmomi sample requests

Tags: pyvmomi

I would like to request a pyvmomi sample which would demonstrate how to to a VM snapshot. What is the Web page that I could use to enter such a request?

Answer (score 0):

Open a new issue here: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/issues

Request the sample and wait for someone to make it.